# TDD approaches for Development DBAs?

Tags: unit-testing, view, db2, tdd, agile

The software development team at my company develops using TDD and BDD practices. Consequently we have lots of unit, integration and acceptance tests to let us know whether our code base is working as expected. Needless to say, we now could not live without these tests giving us constant feedback.

The development DBA on our team writes table views with complex logic. He develops these without unit tests, and they invariably break when he does subsequent development, causing frustration in the software development team.

My question is, are DBAs encouraged to use TDD practices when working in an agile environment? Do DBA's have test frameworks to allow them to work in this way? We use IBM's DB2 database; are there any test frameworks for this database to allow database views to be developed in a TDD manner?

Comment: There are no frameworks for database testing, as far as I know, but I would imagine your DAO (or whatever database abstraction approach you're using) unit tests should cover the database changes nicely.

Comment: There are unit testing frameworks for databases e.g. [tSQLt](http://tsqlt.org/) and a framework has also been introduced into [SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851200(v=vs.103).aspx). However, most DBAs I've spoken to recently don't seem to use as many agaile practices as software developers (perhaps I'm not speaking to the right DBA's!).

As for testing our DAOs/DAL, we achieve this using our integration tests, but as I said this post is looking to see whether DBAs also use unit tests to see errors before the developers in Scrum Sprint (for instance) do.

Comment: I wonder how can you test a view? what are you going to "assert" the definition or the values when executed?

Comment: @AngocA The DBA's I work with create views where some of it's columns hold values which are calculated by processing data in other related tables. Hence a test for a view could be to assert that certain View column values are as expected.

Comment: @Fresh As far as I understand your comment, what you really want to assert is the result set of querying a view, but not the view itself because it does not have data. Am I correct?

Comment: I'd want the DBA to assert the result of a calculated/generated column. As the view generates the column I consider this testing the view. Agree?

Comment: Not really, because what are you going to compare with? with another view? but views by definition are just queries in the catalog. https://github.com/angoca/db2unit/issues/20

Comment: We know exactly what values the View should display. Ideally the DBA should assert these expected values. We find that as the web team has integration tests we see breaking changes before the DBA, as he has no feedback (i.e. DB specific Integration/Unit tests) as to whether he is breaking his views during his development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I've used two approaches:

1. Having a very thin Data Access layer in the application and writing tests around that. In other words (assuming your dba uses sprocs), for each new sproc a method to access it is written and a test is created which exercises it appropriately (or better, tests first). This is nice because it integrates easily with test runners. You can use transactions to rollback tests without side effects.
2. Another option is to use native SQL testing frameworks. I've evaluated [tsqlt](http://tsqlt.org/) which is a SQL Server framework, so not appropriate in your case, but the approach is solid and there could be appropriate frameworks for DB2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sklivvz. Regarding point 1), our DBA writes DB views, and we could write unit tests to verify that what is visible in the table view is what is expected.

I think if we did this, and then encouraged the DBA to keep their eye on a test dashboard which ran periodically, they could then see whether the changes they are making are breaking/not-breaking expectations.

As for 2), that looks good as does the test framework in [SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851200(v=vs.103).aspx). I'll have to use these when I get back to using SQL Server!

Answer (score 1):

There are several framework to test routines in the different kind of databases. Some of them follow the xUnit specification, and this allows to have jUnit-like tests at database level.

For DB2, there is a framework called db2unit: https://github.com/angoca/db2unit

With this framework you can compare objects (numbers, dates, boolean, strings, etc.) like you do in jUnit.

You can include the result of your database level tests into the global tests by capturing the error code, and this can be included in a Continuous Integration system. db2unit uses Travis-CI to test itself.

Comment: +1 for the reference to db2unit, it wasn't created when I wrote this question. Looks promising, I'll pass this info onto the DB2 DBA's which I work with.